# Every complete orthonormal set in a Hilbert space $H$ is an orthonormal basis, if and only if $H$ is finite dimensional.

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, orthonormal

Show that any orthonormal set in a Hilbert space $H$ is linearly independent, and use this to show that $H$ is finite dimensional if and only if every complete orthonormal set is an orthonormal basis.

Attempt:

Trying to show that every orthonormal set is linearly independent is easy if the set is countable, but if it weren't, I'm uncomfortable about considering uncountable sums ($\sum_{\alpha \in I} c_{\alpha}e_{\alpha} = 0$). Anyway around this?

Once I show linear independence, how do prove the claim using it?

Comment: If $H$ is a Hilbert space, then the dimensionality must be such that those possible "uncountable sums" are well defined and the zero condition is met.  Otherwise, the definition of Hilbert space can't be applied to $H$.

Comment: In proving linear independence you only need to look at finite sums.

Comment: I had considered that, but why is that enough?

Comment: Because that's what the definition says.

Comment: Once I show linear independence, how do I use it to prove the claim?

Comment: The question is wrong (or is using unconventional terminology).  In any Hilbert space, a complete orthonormal set is an orthonormal  basis.  It is not, however, a basis in the algebraic sense if the space is infinite-dimensional.

Comment: In any Hilbert space, a complete orthonormal set is an orthonormal basis." This is what I want to show for now, except the Hilbert space in question is finite dimensional.

Comment: @J.G.: How do you define "orthonormal basis"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, your use of the term "orthonormal basis" is unconventional : Usually a complete orthonormal set is an orthonormal basis. However, if the space is infinite dimensional, then such a set cannot be a Hamel basis :

1. Any orthonormal set is linearly independent: You don't need uncountable sums here! If $A$ is an orthonormal set and $\{e_1,e_2,\ldots, e_n\} \subset A$ and $\{\alpha_1,\alpha_2,\ldots, \alpha_n\}$ scalars, then
   $$
   \sum_{i=1}^n \alpha_i e_i = 0 \Rightarrow \alpha_j = \langle \sum_{i=1}^n \alpha_i e_i, e_j\rangle = 0 \quad\forall 1\leq j\leq n
   $$
   Hence, $A$ is linearly independent.
2. If $H$ is a finite dimensional Hilbert space, then every complete orthonormal set has $\dim(H)$ elements. Since they are linearly independent by (1), they must form a Hamel basis.
3. If $H$ is infinite dimensional and $A$ is an orthonormal basis, then $A$ must be infinite (as before). So choose a countable subset $\{e_n : n\in \mathbb{N}\} \subset A$. Then the series
   $$
   \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \left\| \frac{e_n}{n^2} \right\|
   $$
   converges. Since $H$ is complete, there is a vector $x\in H$ such that
   $$
   x = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{e_n}{n^2}
   $$
   Check that $x$ cannot be expressed as a finite linear combination of elements of $A$. Hence, $A$ cannot be a Hamel basis.